# progress bar using js

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I need to adjust the progress bar on a mobile device.

This code is working fine on desktop but in mobile view, the progress bar is moving right of the box extending outside of it.

```js
function startTimerLine(time){
    counterLine = setInterval(timer, 29);
    function timer(){
        time += 1; //upgrading time value with 1
        time_line.style.width = time + "px"; //increasing width of time_line with px by time value
        if(time > 549){ //if time value is greater than 549
            clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://samitsah.com.np/pages/quiz.html) is the link to look at the progress bar in mobile view while playing the quiz.

Comment: You forgot to make a loop to keep updating the progress bar.

Comment: help me plz i am not a programmer...i have been creating my website myself

Comment: **Wait! This isn’t [[tag:java]], this is [[tag:javascript]]!**

Comment: You forgot to call the function.

Comment: and there’s an extra closing brace.